# Equality in Set<Set> Java

Tags: java, string, set, equals, contains

I have a method that returns `Set<Set<String>>`. In my test, I am trying to check if the expected `Set`s are present using `contains()` method.

eg. `input = "cat", "dog", "god"`

`output = [[cat], [dog, god]]`

Now, if I do `output.contains(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("cat")))` it returns `true`.

But if I do `output.contains(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("dog", "god")))` it returns `false`.

According to my understanding, it should return `true` in both cases.

What am I missing here?

```
public class AnagramGroups {
     public Set<Set<String>> group(Set<String> words) {
         Set<Set<String>> groups = new HashSet<>();
         for(String word: words) {
             findAndAdd(word, groups);
         }
         return groups;
     }

     private void findAndAdd(String word, Set<Set<String>> groups) {
         for(Set<String> group: groups) {
             boolean found = false;
             for(String str: group) {
                 if(isAnagram(str, word)) {
                     found = true;
                 }
                 break;
             }
             if(found) {
                 group.add(word);
                 return;
             }
         }
         Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
         set.add(word);
         groups.add(set);
     }

     private boolean isAnagram(String str, String word) {
         Set<Character> characters = new HashSet<>();
         for(char c: str.toCharArray()) {
             characters.add(c);
         }
         for(char c: word.toCharArray()) {
             if(!characters.contains(c)) {
                 return false;
             }
             characters.remove(c);
         }
         return characters.isEmpty();
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Set<Set<String>> groups = new AnagramGroups()
             .group(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("cat", "god", "dog")));
         System.out.println(groups);

         Set set1 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("cat"));
         Set set2 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("god", "dog"));
         System.out.println(groups.contains(set1));
         System.out.println(groups.contains(set2));

         groups.add(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("god", "dog")));
         System.out.println(groups);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is in your `findAndAdd` method, where you are mutating an element (`group`) of the outer `Set` (`groups`), therefore changing its `hashCode()`. As a result, `groups.contains(set2)` cannot find a `Set` that is present in `groups`, since it looks for it in the wrong bucket (matching the new `hashCode()`) instead of the bucket to which it was added (matching the original `hashCode()`).

You can fix your code by removing the `group` `Set` from `groups` before mutating it and then re-add it.

Change your code from:

```
 private void findAndAdd(String word, Set<Set<String>> groups) {
     for(Set<String> group: groups) {
         boolean found = false;
         for(String str: group) {
             if(isAnagram(str, word)) {
                 found = true;
             }
             break;
         }
         if(found) {
             group.add(word);
             return;
         }
     }
     Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
     set.add(word);
     groups.add(set);
 }
```

to:

```
 private void findAndAdd(String word, Set<Set<String>> groups) {
     for(Set<String> group: groups) {
         boolean found = false;
         for(String str: group) {
             if(isAnagram(str, word)) {
                 found = true;
             }
             break;
         }
         if(found) {
             groups.remove(group);
             group.add (word);
             groups.add(group);
             return;
         }
     }
     Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
     set.add(word);
     groups.add(set);
 }
```

When I tried your code and made that change, I got `true` in both cases.

Output:

```
[[cat], [god, dog]]
true
true
[[cat], [god, dog]]
```

Comment: @Eran  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

When you use `Set set2 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("god", "dog"));` You are not checking for a combination  `"god" and "dog"`, but you check for each element `god` then `dog` exist in your `Set<Set<String>>` or not, and in your set you have only one element `cat` is separated. it is like :

```
groups contains `god` -> no
groups contains `dog` -> no

return false
```

To solve your problem you can use equals like so :

```
groups.stream().anyMatch(a -> a.equals(set2))// or groups.stream().anyMatch(set2::equals)
```

or

```
groups.stream().anyMatch(a -> a.containsAll(set2))
```

Comment: The `Set` created by `new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("cat", "god", "dog"))` is not the `Set` on which `groups.contains(set2)` is called. `groups` is generated by the `AnagramGroups`, which groups the "dog" and "god" Strings in the same inner Set.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
static String sort(String s) {
    int[] sortedCP = s.codePoints().sorted().toArray();
    return new String(sortedCP, 0, sortedCP.length);
}

public static Set<Set<String>> group(Set<String> words) {
    Map<String, Set<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (String word : words)
        map.computeIfAbsent(sort(word), k -> new HashSet<>()).add(word);
    return new HashSet<>(map.values());
}
```

And

```
Set<String> words = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("cat", "dog", "god"));
System.out.println(group(words));
```

result:

```
[[cat], [god, dog]]
```

Intermediate variable `map` has

```
{act=[cat], dgo=[god, dog]}
```